# Fs not saving file correctly and how to simplify this code

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I want to save the titles array formatted with line breaks and index of each element.

When I save the 'formatted' object with fs all I get in the file is 'undefined'.

Also, this code is probably really messy and could be simplified, what should I change?

```js
            const $ = cheerio.load(body);
            let titles = [];
            $('div.collection.clearfix').each((i, el) => {
                const title = $(el)
                    .text()
                    .replace(/\n/g, '')
                    .trim()
                    .replace(/ /g, ',');
                titles.push(title);
            })

            let formatted = titles.forEach((i, title) => {
                return title + '. ' + i + '\n'
            });
            fs.writeFile('titles.txt', formatted, (e) => {
                if (e) console.error(e)
            })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You expect

```
            let formatted = titles.forEach((i, title) => {
                return title + '. ' + i + '\n'
            });
```

to return an array.

However, `forEach` returns `undefined`.

You are looking for `titles.map`, which returns an array. Then, you can join all the elements using `Array.prototype.join()` to turn it into a single string